# Scroll two PDFs embed on screen at the same time but individually with touchs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch-event

Actually I have two PDF on my web, displayed at the same time.
With a touch screen, I would like to be able to scroll each pdf at the same time, but touch gesture only capture the first finger.

Any clue?
Thx in advance

Tried using those tags: embed, object, iframe. with same resutl.
I was reading about touch capture evets but i cant find the solution.
Not even sure if the clue is coding or even something to disable on  browser.

i.e. put first finger over first pdf, it scroll perfectly, but if you try to scroll second one, while first finger is still touching the screen, it becomes a zoom/move gesture.

EDIT: I was able to detect both touchs with touchstart, touchend etc. over a normal div,  but not over those iframe, embed or object tag when displaying the pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it sloves your problem:

for this purpose you can use a set of scripts in ExtendScript (JavaScript):

[Dokumente vergleichen (visuell) | InDesign FAQ](https://forums.adobe.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Findesign-faq.de%2Fde%2Fdokumente-vergleichen-visuell)

Use a translation tool to read about it (it's in German).

You could use keyboard shortcuts assigned for the scripts to scroll simultaniously all windows from different documents. Should work in InDesign CS4 and also above.

Direct download link for the scripts:

[[http://indesign-faq.de/files/2009/01/split.zip]](https://forums.adobe.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Findesign-faq.de%2Ffiles%2F2009%2F01%2Fsplit.zip)[2](https://forums.adobe.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Findesign-faq.de%2Ffiles%2F2009%2F01%2Fsplit.zip)

Comment: Thx a lot for your help root, but I really need it to be through touching system due to simulate two readers